# Hibernate 3.2.1.ga caching data

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I've inherited a Java EE webapp composed of struts2 + hibernate 3.2.1 ga deployed on Jboss 4.3.

The application doesn't seem to reflect database changes made intermittently. The values are correct in the database, but when I access the app, the values sometimes show the old records. 
I am extremely green to hibernate, so any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Edit: I had originally stated that the changes are not ever reflected, this was inaccurate, the changes do show up, but on refresh they revert back to the old values.

Comment: maybe a stupid question but did you checked that the app uses the database you think its using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your app is using a second-level cache, and some of the updates are done in the back of Hibernate, using SQL update queries.

This would make the second-level cache unaware that an update has been made to the entity, and the app would thus still show stale data fetched from the second-level cache.